# how to change activity / view when android app are on overview

Tags: java, android

how to hide the app content when it is viewed on overview mode?

i have tried to use the onPause() method to call an alert so that it will cover the screen like the code below, but the alert only show after i go back to the app, it does not show the alert while it is on overview

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        openSearch();
    }
```

i expected the onPause() method to cover the app while it is on overview but it is only called after i resume to the app

Comment: What do you mean by overview mode? Backgrounded?

Comment: Yes, Something like when you click the recent apps button. I guess?

Comment: if you have android there is 3 buttons on the bottom and on the left side there is a button that show all the apps that are active but are on background. it will show a view on the content of the app, i want to hide the content of my app when user click on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following in onCreate of activity. This also blocks the user from taking screenshots of the activity.

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

Comment: this a great answer, but i was thinking of showing a different activity when it is on overview. is there a way i can do that?

Comment: You can try override onStop method in an activity and make the view invisible. I guess it should help